# Existence of right addition/multiplication in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I've seen how to overload `+` and `*` in Ruby, so that
`my_obj + other` calls `my_obj.+(other).` In Python, you do this with `__add__`, and there's a corresponding `__radd__` for overloading `other + my_obj`. Is there really no equivalent right-sided addition/multiplication in Ruby, and does that make it necessary to redefine `+` for each potential class of `other`?

In brief: say I have an object `X` which belongs to some new class defined by me. It's easy to write code for `X + 5`, but it seems that in order to handle `5 + X` I'd need to redefine `Fixnum.+`. Is this true?

Comment: I should clarify: I want 5 + X (and X + 5) to return a custom object of my choice, and not just an integer or float.

Comment: Defining coerce archieves that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you don't need to redefine Fixnum#+ (or any other arithmetic method of ruby's numeric classes). The arithmetic methods of the numeric classes will call `coerce` if the two operands are not the same class. So if you define a coerce method for your class, `5 + instance_of_your_class` will work fine without any changes to Fixnum#+.

Edit: Here's an example of using coerce:

```
class MyNum
  attr_accessor :num

  def initialize(num)
    @num = num
  end

  def +(o)
    lhs, rhs = coerce(o)
    MyNum.new(lhs.num + rhs.num)
  end

  def coerce(o)
    if o.is_a? MyNum
      [self, o]
    else
      [self, MyNum.new(o)]
    end
  end
end

MyNum.new(5)+3 #=> #<MyNum:0x87fca08 @num=8>
3+MyNum.new(5) #=> #<MyNum:0x8807980 @num=8>
```

Answer (score 0):

The RHS is coerced and needs to implement the to_i method which needs to return an appropriate value. The Numeric's classes implementation of to_int will end up calling it as part of the process of addition where other classes are involved on the RHS than strict Numeric descendants.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. If you want to alter the behavior on `5 + x`, you have to redefine + on whatever 5 is, since you're in fact calling `5.+(x)` because of Ruby treating these kinds of operations as mechod calls.